# How can I reconfigure an existing GlassFish installation to detect a fresh JDK install?

Tags: java, glassfish

I had to re-install my JDK and now I get the message "System cannot find the path specified.." error when I try to start GlassFish. Is there a way to update GlassFish to reflect the new JDK installation without having re-install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using GlassFish 3.x and if you want to force a specific JDK install to be used, you can add a AS_JAVA variable in glasfish/config/asenv.conf pointing to that install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables (and restarted your command prompt, if applicable)? I think that's all that's needed. If that doesn't work, you could try re-running the glassfish setup script.